# PreparedStatement.close() vs PreparedStatement = null;

Tags: java

I have a simple question. I have some memory leakage in my code, since I think it is because of the PreparedStatement and ResultSet I want to know that what is the best,safe and correct way to free up the resource and its memory.

`PreparedStatement.close()` or `PreparedStatement = null`?

`ResultSet.close()` or `ResultSet = null`?

Thank you

Comment: PreparedStatement.close() is better

Comment: What evidence do you have that these are the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call close() method on every used Closable object. Clearing the reference isn't enough.

If you just clear the reference, those Statement and ResultSet objects will be closed only when your Connection is closed, and if a ConnectionPool or something alike is used, they will (most probably) never be closed.

EDIT: Closing a connection cause all Statements and ResultSets created by this connection to be closed. Closing a Statement cause all ResultSets created by this Statement to be closed.

Comment: When I close the the resource does the memory is cleared immediately ?

Comment: Sir, Since I am using these resources in a `while(true)` loop , If I close the connection and recreate a new connection in each iteration, will it not consume time and load on the DB. I was creating resources in the beginning of the program and using it in the loop continuously without closing it,with multiple queries. If I close the connection each time , will the creation of the resource will cause any other issues?

Comment: Not much , but as soon the reference to the variable is cleared or as soon as the resource is not in the current scope of the execution then the GC clears them. I hope I am right little bit.

Comment: consider using a tool like https://visualvm.github.io/ to see what is actually leaking and whether your are actually fixing the problem

Comment: *You as Java programmer can not force garbage collection in Java; it will only trigger if JVM thinks it needs a garbage collection based on Java heap size.* [garbage-collection-in-java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.my/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html)